# Z-Index / positioning not working as expected

Tags: html, css, css-position, z-index

I'm trying to position image on top of colored background as shown in attached image.
[image: image positioned top of colored BG]

I've tried setting it's Z-index higher than other elements. Didn't worked.
Set other elements z-index lower than image Z-index. Didn't worked.
Here is the webpage: https://buyshroomsonline.ca/about/

This is the ID of the image (Girls with Phone). As you can see What I'm trying to make it come on top of all other elements.

```
#ctrlimg{
position: relative;
z-index: 10;
top:-160px;}
```

I've also tried setting higher Z-index. Please take a look and help me find what I am missing.
Thanks

Comment: Please post some of your relevant HTML & CSS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove overflow:hidden from `.vc_row[data-vc-full-width]` but make sure do not remove directly from `.vc_row` as it may have a impact on other sections. so inherit or concatenate `.vc_row[data-vc-full-width]` with your custom class.

For Example

```
.yourClass.vc_row[data-vc-full-width]
```

Comment: Thanks brother. I was so frustrated, couldn't think of this.